# ordered partitions of a collection of objects

Tags: combinatorics, factorial

The question states:

"Suppose you have a class of 20 students and the professor decides to assign the students into 5 groups to each work on different projects. The group sizes are 3,4,5,4,4. How many possibilities are there for the formation of 5 groups"

My answer:

This is a direct example of the law of ordered partitions:

$\binom{20}{3,4,5,4,4}$ possibilities for groups.

The question then further states that the groups of four are assigned identical projects. So I get this answer:

$\binom{20}{3,4,5,4,4}$$\frac{1}{3!}$

Here is my question/thought. In this case the group numbers are all 4 that are assigned the same project. Would this answer change if the groups who got the identical projects were say the groups of 3,4, and 5? Would you still get $\binom{20}{3,4,5,4,4}$$\frac{1}{3!}$ ?

Comment: If that were the case, then you would not need the division by $3!$ because even though the *projects* were identical for your groups of size 3,4,5... they would still have been distinguishable to us *based purely on their size*.  In the original, and I had two of the indistinguishable groups next to one another... I wouldn't have been able to remember which was which and who I handed the assignment to first.  In the modified problem, I would remember that I handed the smaller group their assignment before the bigger group and could tell which was which by counting the number of people.

Comment: That makes sense. So since the sizes differ they are still distinguishable even if they got the same project, so we just get the original answer! Awesome.